# Unable to receive the Triggered email sent from marketing cloud using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest

We are currently using REST API to trigger emails to customers.

The API works most of the time, but we have observed that sometimes though the API doesn't throw any errors (has errors in the request sent is false) and record is getting added in the triggered DE, the email is not being sent to the subscriber. The subscriber is added in ALL Subscribers with all the details.

Can anyone help us find out what could be causing the issue as the logs don't show any error.

Answer (score 2):

Could be one of these two things:

**Run-time scripting error**

You can do a Send Preview of the email with the Triggered Send Data Extension (DE) as a source.  That will reveal any scripting issues in the email.  If you have a large number of subscribers in the Triggered Send DE and you know the email address that's not getting the email then you can create a filtered version of the DE with just includes the row for just that single email address.

**Status suppression**

Is the Trigger classified as Transactional?  If not, then the subscriber's status may be preventing delivery.  You can check the classification in the Triggered Send Definition.  If it's set to Commercial and the status of the subscriber in All Subscribers is Unsubscribed or Undeliverable, then that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response Adam . The issue is resolved after we made trigger classified as Transactional and added a primary key to the table.

Comment: I do not recommend adding a primary key to your TSD Data Extension.  It's meant to be a log.  If you add a PK, you'll deal with a lot more failed API calls.  If you need to suppress the number of emails sent, I'd use an exclusion script that looks at your TSD DE.

Comment: Also, if you found my answer helpful, would you checking the check-mark beside it.  I'd appreciate it.  For more information about accepting answers, take a look at this [FAQ](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).